# Real Time (<10ms response) Graphing/Charting

Tags: windows, graphs, scientific-computing

We are trying to find the best professional graphing application for line graphs.

We need an engineering approach that shows data from a hardware device in as near as real time as possible.

The application can be written in any language including c/c++/c#, java, web (api with database), etc.

For example I will have bio data showing a Center of Mass of a human subject (X,Y)
This information will be read into the computer by my program and needs to be output to the screen as a x/y line graph

Comment: [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink) should fit your needs. It works with mathlab and has the abilty to collect data from a external hardware and plot a real time graph.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! "The best" is pretty subjective – we will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @Morty346 Adding some sample graphs would be very helpful

Comment: For which operating system? must it be free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: @Mawg Windows or Linux - And yes it can cost money - depending on the functionality will result in what our budget is - but anywhere from free to a few thousand dollars would be acceptable answers

Comment: How much data is coming in? Asking for a response time is useless if you have megabytes coming in pre second. What hardware device, how is it going to be coupled to the software (i.e. what interface/drivers)?

Comment: all custom made (drivers, hardware, etc) but were literally talking about 2 floats around 100 hz - nothing intensive

Comment: Do you have some example software? I can dig through for specifics - just need help pointed at a few things that might work so that I can go from there

Answer (score 1):

First point is do you need to capture data at better than 10msec per sample **and** display it that quick - it is faster than the response time of the human eye, (TV relies on the fact that a 50 frames/second, i.e. 20 mSec interval, looks steady to the human eye). Or do you need to log the data at that rate and update the display at a more comfortable rate.

Second point is that there is no way that you will get that sort of response time from a web app unless you are on a T1 line, and I am not sure even then.

I think that if you have a task running in background that captures the data and then a foreground task for displaying it you will do OK.

Personally I have done this sort of thing, at reasonable rates but a lot depends on the hardware, with [python](http://python.org) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), with *as suggested above* the data collection in near real time and the display at a human accessable rate.

One of the advantages of using python is the ready availability of libraries to communicate with most hardware types as well as the wide range of plotting possibilities.

Comment: A: this is a human machine study that involves high speed refresh rates
B: this is a local system - internet speed is irrelevant
C: Will check out matplotlib thank you

Comment: @morty346 Re:C: Your question included Web API as an option that you are considering but most *if not all* of the web based tools require a round trip of data to the server and graph back and a lot have either no option to run a local server or a **very** high price to do so.

Comment: again - local test (ie intranet)
there are items out there - I am just not familiar with all of them and was hoping for someone that had more information
heres an example -  http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html